# XCode 14.2 Another Command PhaseScriptExecution failed error

Tags: build, xcode14

So I'm stuck with the Command PhaseScriptExecution failed error and have been reading a lot of suggestions on possible fixes. I have re-installed PODs and tried a new certificate. My code runs fine, for a while, and then frustratingly fails with the above error code. I quit XCode, re-open and sometimes its works for 10-15 min., other times it fails immediately. It looks like I may be missing a file or folder per my Build log:

```
PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Copy\ XCFrameworks /Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/F1CD-emwkofgjspicwrayhniokxrlpenk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleAppMeasurement.build/Script-3620B48AE6C009A94EF9C2906A7D6E1C.sh (in target 'GoogleAppMeasurement' from project 'Pods')
    cd /Users/myname/Desktop/F1CD/Pods
    /bin/sh -c /Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/F1CD-emwkofgjspicwrayhniokxrlpenk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleAppMeasurement.build/Script-3620B48AE6C009A94EF9C2906A7D6E1C.sh

Selected xcframework slice ios-arm64_i386_x86_64-simulator
rsync --delete -av --filter P .*.?????? --links --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" "/Users/myname/Desktop/F1CD/Pods/GoogleAppMeasurement/Frameworks/GoogleAppMeasurementIdentitySupport.xcframework/ios-arm64_i386_x86_64-simulator/*" "/Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/F1CD-emwkofgjspicwrayhniokxrlpenk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/GoogleAppMeasurement/AdIdSupport"
building file list ... done

sent 238 bytes  received 20 bytes  516.00 bytes/sec
total size is 48003  speedup is 186.06
Copied /Users/myname/Desktop/F1CD/Pods/GoogleAppMeasurement/Frameworks/GoogleAppMeasurementIdentitySupport.xcframework/ios-arm64_i386_x86_64-simulator to /Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/F1CD-emwkofgjspicwrayhniokxrlpenk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/GoogleAppMeasurement/AdIdSupport
Selected xcframework slice ios-arm64_i386_x86_64-simulator
rsync --delete -av --filter P .*.?????? --links --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" "/Users/myname/Desktop/F1CD/Pods/GoogleAppMeasurement/Frameworks/GoogleAppMeasurement.xcframework/ios-arm64_i386_x86_64-simulator/*" "/Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/F1CD-emwkofgjspicwrayhniokxrlpenk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/GoogleAppMeasurement/WithoutAdIdSupport"
building file list ... rsync: link_stat "/Users/myname/Desktop/F1CD/Pods/GoogleAppMeasurement/Frameworks/GoogleAppMeasurement.xcframework/ios-arm64_i386_x86_64-simulator//*" failed: No such file or directory (2)
done

sent 29 bytes  received 20 bytes  98.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/aaefcfd1-5c95-11ed-8734-2e32217d8374/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync/main.c(996) [sender=2.6.9]
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Can someone help with what I can try next?

Comment: Any resolution? @DHHJ?

Comment: I basically copied existing code, file by file, into a new project and it now works flawlessly. Who knew!